# React JS: set all values of nested object to false except for one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component has the following state:

```
this.state = {
  models: {
    model1: false,
    model2: true,
    model3: false,
    model4: false
  },

  state1: 'somevalue',
  state2: 5,
  state3: false

}
```

When the `onButtonClick()` function is called, I want all values of `this.state.models` to be all `false` except for the value corresponding to the `key` variable:

```
onButtonClick(e){
  const key = e.target.getAttribute('model');

  this.setState({
   models:{
     //set all states to false except for the key
   }
  })
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your browser [supports spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), then the updated `models` object could be obtained by that syntax, and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as described below:

```js
onButtonClick(e){
  const key = e.target.getAttribute('model');
  
  // Get reference to current models object in state
  const models = this.state.models;

  
  
  // Compose new state object by..
  const state = { 
    models : 
    Object
    .keys(models) // Get list of keys in model
    .reduce((result, k) => { 
      // Reduce keys to object of key/value pairs
      // where key match is set to true
      return { ...result, [k] : key === k };
    }, {})
  }

  this.setState(state)
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks it worked, and thanks for the explanation <3

Answer (score 2):

You can use computed object properties to get it to work. `this.setState` does a shallow merge and you will have to spread the properties nested one level deep.

```
onButtonClick(e){
  const key = e.target.getAttribute('model');

  this.setState({
   models:{
     // spread all the properties for models
     ...this.state.models,
     [key]: true // set the key prop to false
   }
  })
}
```

If we want to make sure, other attrs are always false, then override the values before the state is being set.

```
onButtonClick(e){
      const key = e.target.getAttribute('model');
      const updatedModels = Object.entries(this.state.models)
                                  .reduce((memo, [currKey]) => {
         if(currKey === key) {
             memo[currKey] = true;
         } else {
             memo[currKey] = false;
         }       

  
         return memo;
      }, {});
    
      this.setState({
       models: updatedModels
      })
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't set the rest to false.

Comment: This is under the assumption not more than one attribute will be set to false at the same time.