# Set all values of nested object to false except for one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have this `setState` to control my panel open/close state somewhat similar to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995010/react-js-set-all-values-of-nested-object-to-false-except-for-one). And I'm trying to `open one panel at one time` so there will be only **one** true value in the `state`.
Here's my code:

```js
// Parents component
const [show, setShow] = useState({
    1 : false,    // id=1 when passed to child component (using another props but 
    2 : false,    // dont worry, I'm passing it correctly)
    3 : false,    // id=3 and so on...
    4 : false,
    5 : false,
    6 : false
  })

//Child component 
// id is used to check which panel is in open/close state
const handleShowPanel = (id) => {
    const val = !props.show
    // props.setShow(prev => ({...prev, [key[0].charCodeAt(0)]: false}))
    props.setShow(prev => ({...prev, [id] : val}))  //this is the one i'm using
    // props.setShow(prev => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(prev).map(([k, v]) => Number(k) !== id ? [k, !v] : [k, false])))
  }
```

The code that I'm using works perfectly fine opening and closing one panel by another one.
Here's a [picture for better illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZdfq.jpg), let's say first I opened the `Panel 1`, after that when I clicked `Panel 2` I want to **close Panel 1** while `opening Panel 2`. So I will have to set all other values to false **except** the panel that I'm opening. It is like [accordian mode in ant design](https://ant.design/components/collapse/#components-collapse-demo-accordion)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one panel open at-a-time then why not just store the id of the panel you want open?

The parent component owns ***both*** the state and the handler functions to update it, it passes down to each panel the currently opened id and a the callback to toggle open a new panel.

```
const [showId, setShowId] = useState(null); // <-- initially none open

const handleShowPanel = (id) => {
  // if already open, close it, otherwise set to new id to
  // close previous and open next
  setShowId(showId => showId === id ? null : id);
};
```

Then when mapping/rendering the panels just check the current panel's `id` against the currently set `showId` state value to set the open status/prop accordingly.

Comment: Tried it but it doesnt work as I wanted it to. I used object value for each panel so that I can control or know which panel is in open/close. Using the solution you gave will let all panels receive the same `props.show`. Here's my full code for [parent](https://pastebin.com/s2p7NDaU) and for [child](https://pastebin.com/kdwxqdgJ)

Comment: @Leo Ah, I see, I neglected to mention that the parent component has the state and the handler and should pass the `handleShowPanel` down to children as a callback. The children panels, when interacted with call back to the parent to have the state updated. I'll make this more clear. Sorry.

Comment: @Leo I took a look at those two pastebins and I seems more like what you are calling the "child" is what I would consider to be the parent component rendering the panels. If you need more help from here though a *running* codesandbox for us to work from would be great.

Comment: I've made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-colden-4yqo1) here but there's some small issue when opening 2 or more panels. I'm not sure how to fix it.. cause it's my first time using codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you may not need to keep show state for all panels, only keep the opened panel index try this way

```
const panels = [
    {id:1, name:'name1', description:'description 11'},
    {id:1, name:'name2', description:'description 22'},
    {id:1, name:'name3', description:'description 33'},
    {id:1, name:'name4', description:'description 44'},
    {id:1, name:'name5', description:'description 55'},
    {id:1, name:'name6', description:'description 66'}
]

const PanelParent = () => {
    const [openId, setOpenId] = useState('') //set an id if you need to open a default panel
    const handleShowPanel = (id) => {
        setOpenIndex(openId == id ? false : id)
    }
    return <>
        {panels.map(d => {
            return  <Panel data={d} handleShowPanel={handleShowPanel} open={openId == d.id}/>
        })}
    </>
}
```

Comment: I'm using `Ant Design Collapse` and  using the`onChange` to keep track for each panel. So I have to individually control each panel. Here's my full code for [parent](https://pastebin.com/s2p7NDaU) and for [child](https://pastebin.com/kdwxqdgJ)