# Set all object keys to false in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a much more simpler question which will eventually solve [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001183/set-all-values-of-nested-object-to-false-except-for-one). So how do I change this `show` which is in `Component A` from `Component B`?
Component A:

```js
  const [show, setShow] = useState({
    1 : false,
    2 : false,
    3 : false,
    4 : false,
    5 : false,
    6 : false
  })
```

Component B:

```js
const handleShowPanel = (id) => {
    //how do I reset them here
  }
```

Comment: what's the component structure?

Comment: *"So how do I change this show which is in Component A from Component B?"* I'm afraid I don't understand what that's asking.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wanna change the object value from all false to all true or from all true to all false in another component. Which means this object is in ·`Component A` and the `function` is in `Component B`

Comment: @Leo - A component can't reach out and change the state of another component, only the component can change its state. (It can provide a function to the other component that the other component can call to change it, though that can easily be misused [it's most useful when the target of the change is the parent of the source of the change].)

Comment: Elevate `show` state to the parent of A and B.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here's my sandbox for [better illustration](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-colden-4yqo1)

Comment: @Leo The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @morganney What does that mean

Comment: @Leo https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but I'll try to write some code on what I undertstand.

```
function Parent() {
const panels = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

  const [panelsShowing, setPanelsShowing] = useState({
    0: false,
    1: false,
    2: false,
    3: false,
    4: false,
    5: false,
  })

  const togglePanelShowing = useCallback((index) => {
    setPanelsShowing(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [index]: !prevState[index]
     }))
  },[setPanelsShowing])

  return (
      <div>
        {panels.map((onePanel, panelIndex) => {
          return (<Panel 
                isShowing={panelsShowing[panelIndex]} 
                togglePanelShowing={() => togglePanelShowing(panelIndex)}
              />)
           })}
      </div>
     )
  }

const Panel = ({ isShowing, togglePanelShowing }) => 
 isShowing ? (
     <div>
        <button onClick={togglePanelShowing}>Toggle!</button>
      </div>
   ) 
    : null
```

I also see that you wrote that you actually want to have the toggle function in the child, that is simple, pass the setShow to the child component and recreate the toggle function inside it.

```
<Panel setPanelsShowing={setPanelsShowing} />
```

another thing that I want to say, if the show Object is all you have and actually you don't have an array of elements, then you can still use the same toggle show function but instead of mapping through panels you would map with Object.entries of the show object and the key would be the number and the value would be the boolean if it's showing or not.

for example:

```
const toggleShowing = (number) => {
  setPanelsShowing(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     [number]: !prevState[number]
  }))
}

// in the JSX return:
Object.entries(panelsShowing).map(([number, isShowing]) => (<Panel isShowing={isShowing} toggleShowing={() => toggleShowing(number)}/>))
```

maybe if you added more to your question I could understand it better, but from what I understand you have an array of some elements and you want to decide if the element is showing based on the index. Or you have an object with the keys being the number and the value being wether it is showing or not.

Comment: Yes the objects' keys represent the `number of the panel` and the value represents if the panel is in `open/close state`. So I would just want to change the value of the objects to all false as my object is in `Component A` and the function that I wanna change the objects' value is in `Component B`.